# Problem with EC2 t3.micro being unresponsive (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mediawiki

For a few weeks I've been trying to find out the reason for random downtimes of an EC2 (t3 micro, has a root volume and and additional EBS volume, both gp3).

In EC2 logs (journalctl) there are some errors from awsagent failing to get instance-id from metadata. Shortly after this message the instance becomes unresponsive (that's looking at the time of this message in the logs and the time of outages).

Errors reference Publishers/ArsenalPublisher and Core/MetaDataClient. Stopping/starting the instance brings it back to life.
During the downtimes, CPU usage goes up to 60-65%, Read throughput on the root volume spikes too (there is not much traffic to the instance in general, though), the applications on the server are unavailable, and it's impossible to SSH into it. Logs of CPU usage by process during the downtime show that no process is using more than 1% of the CPU.

Sometimes the instance still shows as healthy, sometimes 1 out of 2 health checks fails.
On the server (which is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) there is a Wordpress site and a Mediawiki install. There is a mySQL database, and data has been moved to the additional EBS volume.
Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Go to CloudWatch when this happens, and look at the CPU credit balance for the instance. If it's zero, then you need a bigger instance.

Comment: As for the errors: if you show the _exact_ error, _with stack trace_, then somebody might be able to help you with that. But it's unlikely that anybody knows what `ArsenalPublisher` is.

Comment: Check the RAM usage as well. You will need a custom solution to monitor it.

Comment: @Parsifal CPU credit balance dips slightly during the outage, but there's plenty left

Comment: I don't think that t3.micro for a MediaWiki is enough.

Comment: Refer to this URL  -  https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/    specifically the line naming candidates  -  T3 instances are also an affordable option to run your code repositories and development and test environments.  Please - Notice it does not mention production environments.

Comment: If you would like to try to rescue your t3.micro - Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.